# Program to find sum of prime numbers between 1 and 10^7

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)    
{
    flag=0;

    for(j=2;j<=sqrt(i);j++) //Looping till square root of n times
    {
        if(i%j==0) 
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag==0)
        sum+=i;
}
```

Time taken to run is more than 5 seconds,
but the time limit that the question demands is less than 5 seconds.
Could anyone suggest a optimized solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Use a [sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) on the range and then sum the primes you find.

Comment: 2 is prime.  All other prime numbers are odd, that will effectively halve the number of numbers you have to check.

Comment: instead of checking with all numbers just check with previously found prime numbers and of course skip even numbers.

Comment: `j<=sqrt(i)` is equivalent to `j*j<=i`, but multiplication is much faster. (Needs `unsigned long long`). Also, when `j*j==i` then `i` obviously is a square, not a prime.

Comment: @MSalters `unsigned long long` isn't needed in `j*j<=i` since the loop will finish long before `j*j` overflows. Also, most probably the compiler optimized calculation of `sqrt(i)` to move it outside of the loop.

Comment: The time complexity is O(n log log n) with using sive of Eratosthenes and if n = 10^7 you can calculate in 1 secs.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<uint> primes = {2,3,5};
bool check_prime(uint x){    
    bool result = true;
    for(auto i: primes){
        if(i*i>x){
            break;
        }
        if(x%i==0){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(result){
        primes.push_back(x);
    }
    return result;
}

void get_primes(){
    for(uint x =6; i<N; i++){
        check_prime(x);
    }
}

uint get_sum(){
    return std::accumulate(primes.begin(), primes.end(), 0, std::plus);
}
```

Comment: And, what do you want to tell us?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: check % == 0 only for "known" prime numbers, not all numebrs in [2;sqrt(x)]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

This algorithm will optimize your code.